# How to pass type arguments when using a django generic class based view?

Tags: python, django, generics, types, django-class-based-views

I want to use **django.views.generic.edit.FormView** and since it's a generic, I'm giving it a type argument (MyForm):

```
class MyView(FormView[MyForm]):
    ...
```

But it causes this error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

What's the proper way to pass type arguments to **FormView**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options (or three, if you include ignoring the error in mypy)

### Monkeypatching

Monkeypatch the classes at runtime by putting

```py
import django_stubs_ext

django_stubs_ext.monkeypatch()
```

in your `<mysite>/settings.py` file

https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs#i-cannot-use-queryset-or-manager-with-type-annotations

### `TypeAlias` behind `TYPE_CHECKING` guard

```py
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
  MyFormView = FormView[MyForm]
else:
  MyFormView = FormView

class MyView(MyFormView)):
  ...
```

this means you don't need `django-stubs-ext` as a runtime dependency.

Comment: I used the second approach: "TypeAlias behind TYPE_CHECKING guard" and it worked! thanks.